# displaying characters in a dot matrix

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, character

I've built a matrix of LEDs controlled by a Java program on my Raspberry Pi. I want to display characters on this matrix. So what I need to do is convert the characters to a two-dimensional boolean-Array (each LED is represented by one boolean).

The only way to do this I can think of is to design a separate matrix for each existing character, but this is way to much work.

Is there any way to do this differently?

Comment: How big an LED grid do you have?  Do they support intermediate values or just on and off?

Comment: You might want to learn about MCUFONT:  https://github.com/mcufont/mcufont

Comment: P.S., Re, "The only way to do this I can think of is ... way to much work." Sigh! Kids these days! When *I* was a young whipper-snapper, I designed my font as ASCII art, in a text editor, and then I wrote a Pascal program that generated Pascal source code for an initialized array of packed bits, based on the contents of the ASCII art file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could rasterize (draw) a given font at a given point size using something like AWT or FreeType and then examine the image to see which pixels/LEDs should be on or off.

This will break down as the font size gets smaller.  Below some point, you're probably better off coming up with the matrixes yourself rather than pouring a bunch of effort into something that doesn't work.

OTOH, "render-and-read" would be Much Less Boring... so YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

you could load a monochrome image for a character with a pixel size regarding to your led matrix and check with two for loops, whether a pixel at a certain position is black (true) or white (false).